# facebook oauth url problems

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-login

I have the following code, which are working partly

```
<?php

   require_once 'facebook.php';

   $app_id = 'MY_APP_ID';
   $app_secret = 'MY_APP_SECRET';
   $app_url = 'http://mysite.com/index.php/';
   $scope = 'user_about_me';

   // Init the Facebook SDK
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId'  => $app_id,
     'secret' => $app_secret,     
     'cookie' => true
   ));

   // Get the current user
   $user = $facebook->getUser();

   // If the user has not installed the app, redirect them to the Auth Dialog
   if (!$user) {
     $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
       'scope' => $scope,
       'redirect_uri' => $app_url,
     ));

     print('<script> top.location.href=\'' . $loginUrl . '\'</script>');
   } 

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    echo "id: " . $user_profile['id'];   

 ?>
```

I get the correct id printed out on this page, but on several other pages i go into the if(!$user).

But there is an error in the oauth url:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

I have found similar problems here on stackoverflow, but can't seem to fix it :/

Under my settings I have the same url and $app_url

Website with facebook -> site url -> https://www.facebook.com/pages/myappname/373671679372127/

EDIT: I edit my app_url, so it is now the same as my canvas url under app settings: http://mysite.com/index.php/

Now I don't get an error. I just get a blank window :(

EDIT: Importent to clear cookies once a while when testing. Else some very random errors somewhere

Comment: Are you sure your domain is filled in "App Domains" when editing the application in Facebook Developers? Fill there your main domain if you want to give total access of your application in your webapp, without being restrict of having a subdomain or not.

Comment: my app domain is: mywebsite.com (without http and any /). Facebook kept complaining nomatter what I wrote in there

Answer (score 1):

Check if you set the correct URL for "Website with Facebook Login" in the dev settings. This cannot be a page on facebook.com, it has to be a Link to YOUR domain.

Also, i would enclose the last 2 rows of your code in an "else" block. And the JavaScript code is wrong. This would be correct:

```
print('<script> top.location.href="' . $loginUrl . '";</script>');
```

(easier to understand with double quotes, you missed a semicolon. even if it´s not always needed, you better use it)

Try this code:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();

   // If the user has not installed the app, redirect them to the Auth Dialog
   if (!$user) {
     $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
       'scope' => $scope,
       'redirect_uri' => $app_url,
     ));
     print('<script> top.location.href=\'' . $loginUrl . '\';</script>');
   }
   else {
    echo 'User ID: ' . $user;
   }
```

Also, get rid of the Slash after "index.php". That´s not i folder (i hope/guess).

Comment: In some files I get error if it is included and some I get error if it is not included.
In this file I got it, but forgot to post it sorry.
My app secret is btw fake :) But I'll fix that

Comment: I did echo the URL and put it into my adress bar. But still gives me blank page :(

Comment: so, the loginurl gives you a blank page? are you logged in on facebook?

Comment: also check if the sandbox mode is enabled, test it with an app admin logged in.

Comment: I am logged in. I test with both the admin and a test user. Sandbox mode is disabled

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19579/discussion-between-pavenhimself-and-luschn)